# UWP app drops stack owerflow exception when turning on XAML switch by code C#

Tags: c#, xaml, exception, uwp, uwp-xaml

I use the IsOn property of toggle switches and when I try to both get, and set the IsOn property of a switch, it just crashes with system.stack overflow exception.
How can solve this? Or can I set the state of toggle switch with other methods?
(the Switch1_Toggled happens by human interaction, before the turnit method)

```
    public void turnit()
    {
        Switch1.IsOn = true;
    }

    public void Switch1_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Switch1.IsOn)
        {
            request = "11";
        }
        else
        {
            request = "10";
        }
        SendRequest();
        //ReceiveResponse();
        //statusupdater();
        turnit();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encountering an infinite loop. When you toggle the switch via `Switch1.IsOn = true;`, it will trigger your handler method `Switch1_Toggled`, which in turn calls `turnit()`, which in turn...

A stack overflow occurs because there is not enough room in stack memory to store the infinite depth of call heirarchy.

Remove the call to `turnit` inside the handler and you should be good.

Comment: Tanks! If I call `turnit()` by an other method, it won't have error? I thought that the toggled event only could happen by user interaction... Really big thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: Correct: calling `turnit()` elsewhere is fine. I've only built a few UWP apps, but from what I can tell the bindings and event handlers work fairly consistently all the time, even when called from code-behind (as opposed to say, WinForms apps in some situations). Glad to help! Happy coding!